# Cannot access a disposed object on form close

Tags: vb.net, exception

I am trying to make some code for a game that has a grid and a tick counter but the grid just tries to fill the window instead of stopping and does not display the tick counter. The error that keeps coming up is:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

I have no idea what this means and I don't know how to fix it.

Heres my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim G As Graphics
    Dim BBG As Graphics
    Dim BB As Bitmap
    Dim r As Rectangle

    Dim tSec As Integer = TimeOfDay.Second
    Dim tTicks As Integer = 0
    Dim MaxTicks As Integer = 0

    Dim IsRunning As Boolean = True

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Show()
        Me.Focus()

        G = Me.CreateGraphics
        BB = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)

        StartGameLoop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DrawGraphics()
        For X = 0 To 19
            For Y = 0 To 14
                r = New Rectangle(X * 32, Y * 32, 32, 32)

                G.FillRectangle(Brushes.BurlyWood, r)
                G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r)
            Next
        Next
        G.DrawString("Ticks: " & tTicks & vbCrLf & _
                    "TPS: " & MaxTicks, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 650, 0)

        G = Graphics.FromImage(BB)

        BBG = Me.CreateGraphics
        BBG.DrawImage(BB, 0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)

        G.Clear(Color.Wheat)
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartGameLoop()
        Do While IsRunning = True
            Application.DoEvents()



            DrawGraphics()

            TickCounter()
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub TickCounter()
        If tSec = TimeOfDay.Second And IsRunning = True Then
            tTicks = tTicks + 1
        Else
            MaxTicks = tTicks
            tTicks = 0
            tSec = TimeOfDay.Second
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: can you please try the trick i given you might help you to locate your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are utilizing a lot of bad practice here...

First of all, using `Me.CreateGraphics()` is bad and the resulting object can only be drawn with once, which means that you are forced to call it several times. Continuously calling it will just create more and more graphics objects that increases memory usage. Even if you were to dispose of them every time you've finished drawing it's still a huge bottleneck because it slows down processing.

Secondly, using `Application.DoEvents()` is ***VERY BAD PRACTICE*** and will burn your CPU in a loop like that. Unless used correctly (which you don't) it can cause unexpected and unpredictable behaviour. The error you're getting is a good example of such unexpected behaviour.

I suggest you read this MSDN blog, it explains exactly why one ***shouldn't*** use `Application.DoEvents()`: [***Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents***](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/).

---

Instead, in order to do this correctly:

- Replace `Me.CreateGraphics()` with your form's [**`Paint` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) and do all the drawing in there through the `e.Graphics` object.
- Replace your game loop with a [**`Timer`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) that continuously calls [**`Me.Invalidate()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx) to redraw the form.

For example:

```
Dim WithEvents GameTimer As New Timer() With {.Interval = 1}

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GameTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private GameTimer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GameTimer.Tick
    Me.Invalidate() 'Redraw the form.
    TickCounter()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Wheat)

    For X = 0 To 19
        For Y = 0 To 14
            Dim r As New Rectangle(X * 32, Y * 32, 32, 32)

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.BurlyWood, r)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r)
        Next
    Next

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Ticks: " & tTicks & vbCrLf & _
                          "TPS: " & MaxTicks, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 650, 0)
End Sub
```